# What are some of the best ways to shell an egg?

Tags: eggs, hard-boiled-eggs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to peel hard boiled eggs easily?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-to-peel-hard-boiled-eggs-easily)

I just came back from the kitchen where I was preparing a dozen hard boiled eggs for a recipe.  Part of this preparation is removing each of the egg's shell. The best tip I've heard yet is to shock the eggs in ice water directly after pulling them off a boil, cracking each end and pealing across the hemisphere. This works about 50/50 for me. That's to say half of my eggs are unpresentable. I've been told also only to hard/soft-boil old eggs, which for obvious reasons isn't always practical.

What's the best way to shell a hard/soft-boil chicken egg?

Answer (score 4):

This is what we do where I work: dump them into a bucket full of cold water with the tap still running. We crack the side of the shell against the side of the sink & roll it til it's cracked all around, then peel. I am sure there are other ways though. 
I think shocking them helps them shell easily, but also cools them down for foodsafe reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give is to use older eggs if you're not eating them from the shell. As they get older, they get easier to peel and the yolk is easier to remove (if you remove the yolk).

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog:

http://thestonesoup.com/blog/2012/01/the-new-secret-to-easy-to-peel-boiled-eggs/

http://thestonesoup.com/blog/2010/03/the-secret-to-easy-to-peel-boiled-eggs/

So, her *secret* is older eggs, and increase ph of boiling water using baking soda.