# Does it matter if I start boiling hard eggs in hot or cold water?

Tags: eggs, temperature, boiling, hard-boiled-eggs

Does it matter if I in which water temperature I start to prepare hard eggs?

Of course, the preparing time will be still measured from boiling - but does it make any difference? - regards the temperature difference between the eggs and the water.

Also, in case it do matters - does it matter if the eggs were in the fridge or in room temperature?

Comment: The probably most comprehensive test on boiling eggs: https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/the-secrets-to-peeling-hard-boiled-eggs.html

Comment: I have heard starting from cold water reduces/ eliminates the green from around the yoke.

Comment: @Optionparty I don't think that's entirely true - I usually start with boiling water, and there's no green. I pretty sure it's related to the cooking time.

Comment: The green layer around the yolk of a hardboiled egg is created because the egg was overcooked and no other reason

Comment: Placing cold eggs in hot water will often cause them to crack.

Comment: @Norm You mean that they will crack immediately, or while cooking? Cause the first one never happened to me

Comment: I have an instant hot water dispenser, that dispenses water at about 180 degrees - if I drop cold eggs right out of the fridge into the hot water they immediately crack. So I put them in some lukewarm water from the tap and then onto the stove. I time them so as soon as I get a rolling boil, I turn the heat off, cover the pan and let it cool for 20 minutes, then rinse with cold water. They come out very consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how fussy you are about your hard boiled eggs. If you wait until your water is boiling and then add the eggs for the same amount of time, every time, then you will get consistent results. If you add the eggs to cold water a variety of circumstances (actual starting water temp, stove setting, size/style of the pan) will make your results 'inconsistent'.

If you know you like a 12 minute hard boiled egg then you need to start with boiling water or you will get runnier eggs. Once the water reaches 212°F (100°C) it will remain there so long as the same amount of heat is being used. The boiling point of your water (based on other chemicals in the water and altitude) becomes a constant temperature to cook your eggs.

For 'consistency' yes, it matters.

Comment: Start cold and move 12 to 10 is pretty darn consistent.

Comment: if and ONLY IF you use the same heating element, pan, volume of water and starting water temp...

Comment: I will hold with pretty darn consistent.  Change the pan and you think you could tell the difference?

Comment: This answer applies to the usual method in which the eggs are submerged in water.  If the eggs are instead steamed using a very small amount of water, you should start with boiling water so the eggs heat evenly.  The steaming method also has very consistent results.

Comment: So it can only change if I want to be very consistent? But regards the egg quality - it doesn't matter, correct? (For example, like in potatoes it's better to start with cold)

Comment: quality requires consistency. you have expectations of what you will find when you open up that egg. If you truly don't care what you find inside...then, no, it doesn't matter. Eggs boiled for too little will be runny and soft...too long dry and hard. If you learn, working with your equipment (pan, stove and tapwater) that 15 minutes from fridge to hard boiled is 'eggsactly' (couldn't resist) what you are after then you have found 'your formula'. If you want to know how do consistently achieve a desired result regardless of what equipment you are using then start with your water boiling.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is they are easier to peel if the water starts cold (or warm from faucet).  It is certainly easier to stack the eggs in cold water.  But all people may not have the same experience.

See my answer [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-to-peel-hard-boiled-eggs-easily/78415#78415).

Comment: Kenji from SeriousEats [disagrees with the easier peeling](https://www.seriouseats.com/2014/05/the-secrets-to-peeling-hard-boiled-eggs.html).

Comment: @Stephie I used to be a cook and peeled literally 1000's and 1000s of eggs and this is what I settled on.

Comment: So as I understand, it can only make a difference in the peeling process? (I usually start with already boiling water, and have no problems with peeling them - I just wash them in cold water when they're ready)